# Angular5 + ChartJS - Multiple charts stacking on top of each other?

Tags: angular, chart.js

So could use some help, i thought i had this working, but upon playing with the graph i realized i do not.

In ngOnInit i subscribe to one of my services that returns an observable containing the data i need to produce the chart  that i need.  This subscription is inside of a router params subscription that monitors when the user changes child pages within the same component so i can update the page data, standard Angular stuff.

I thought it was working perfectly, i would switch routes, my chart would rebuild, all my other data values would update on the page and life was good.

Until i started playing with the Y axis after changing routes, my chart started flickering between my current route's chart and the chart from the previous route!  I am pretty sure i am doing things in the wrong order, or missing something to keep it from rebuilding another chart on top of the existing one?

Heres a gif of  whats happening
https://gyazo.com/dd87de46b282094f88cda41189910c00

Here is a high level look at the order i do things, i wont bother filling in the hundred or so lines of other stuff going on unless necessary i think this gives the jist.

```
chart = [] as Chart;

ngOnInit
{
    router.params.subscribe(params => {
    //Set a few var's based on param's here
     apiService.getData()
    .subscribe(res => {
        timestamps = res.history.map((x) =>x.time)
        data = res.data.map((y) => y.data)
        chart = new Chart('canvas' }{
        //Normal  ChartJS stuff in here
        labels = timestamps;
        data = data;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Ive tried clearing my chart with this.chart = [] as Chart; inside my params subscription to clear it and its data when the child route changes, but it didnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?